# Downloading the new BCC

Tags: wallet

Hi people of North Cryptoland. I bought a couple of Bitcoin a few months ago with a long term view for my retirement, just to add to the portfolio. They are stored in a Bitcoin Multibit HD wallet (in brown leather nicely embossed I imagine!) Anyway I am just wondering how does one find the new BCC if I am entitled, and how do I download them into my Wallet or do I need a new Wallet? (you know in black leather - sort of bill fold style I imagine!). Be gentle with me, I'm 54 years old and my level of computer savvy, runs all the way up to being able to start my computer most days, if I've remembered to plug it in to the wall socket that is...

Thanxs in Advance.  Shady @ Australia

Comment: You need to have a bit of technical knowledge to do it yourself. Please have a look at the link above ^

Comment: Thanxs Sufiyan...

Answer (score 0):

For a start multibit is no longer being developed , so i highly advice you move your bitcoins out of it into another wallet. It is not possible to access bitcoin cash using multibit. Which version of the software do you have and how many (ONLY the number) seeds do you have to restore your wallet?

[Blog](https://www.multibit.org/blog/2017/07/26/multibit-shutdown.html) post suggests how you can import it to electrum. And further [post](https://electrum.org/bcc2.txt) on electrum suggest how you can claim BCC. You will need to fiddle a bit here , but this certainly is possible and be very careful where you get the files from as this will potentially put your coins at risk.

Once you have both the balances available , I highly suggest you move to a hardware wallet like ledger nano s or trezor they are dead simple to use and setup.

**Disclaimer** : I have not used electrum or multibit and the answer above is after a quick research.